# Create deb package using CPack for different targets

Tags: cmake, cpack, cmakelists-options

I have base_project, looks like this:

```
base_project
├── apps
│   ├── subproject_1
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── src
│   ├── subproject_2
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── src
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── package
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── debian
│   │   ├── postinst
│   │   ├── preinst
│   │   └── prerm
│   └── services
│       ├── subproject-1.service
│       └── subproject-1.service
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

In cmake files `apps/subproject_*` i have name and executable of the project. For example subproject_2:

```
project(subproject_2 VERSION 1.0.0)
add_executable(subproject_2)
```

My cmake package looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/apps/subproject_1/resources DESTINATION /opt/base_project/subproject_1)
install(TARGETS subproject_1 DESTINATION /opt/base_project/subproject_1)
install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION /var/opt/base_project DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS
    OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ OWNER_EXECUTE
    GROUP_WRITE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE
    WORLD_WRITE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
)

if (NOT CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    install(TARGETS subproject_1 DESTINATION /opt/base_project)
    set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libsdl2-2.0-0, qt5-default")
else()
    install(FILES services/subproject_1.service DESTINATION /etc/systemd/system/)
    string(CONCAT CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/prerm;"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/preinst;"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/postinst"
    )
    set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "armhf")
endif()

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "someone")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "subproject_1")
include(CPack)
```

In my root cmake just included package directory:
`add_subdirectory(package)`

This is how I build package:

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . -j`npoc` --target package
```

The problem is base_project includes subproject_1 and some other utils.
I need to get deb package of subproject_2 with cmake build target.

How can I do that with base_project (includes subproject_1) and sub_project_2 with two different targets?

What I mean:

base_project (includes subproject_1). Get base_project.deb:

```bash
cmake --build . -j`npoc` --target package
```

subproject_2. Get subproject_2.deb:

```bash
cmake --build . -j`npoc` --target package_sub_project_2
```

I tried to make another directory called subproject_2_package with debian preinst, postinst etc and cmake, but not sure how to do it right